# Any way to work out closest marker to a specific location in Google My Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

I'm using **Google My Maps** and I have added a bunch of locations, for examples sake, just say I added a bunch of Gyms.

Now I have a map with the location markers of several different Gyms - now say I want to enter a location such as my home address and/or work address.

Is there any way I can easily work out (either by estimated time **or** distance) the closest Gym to my Home and/or Work address - or does that involve having to mess around with the distance markers each time I add a new address I want to check what the closest Gym is to it?